# Why does F# compiler check `this != null`?

Tags: f#

F# compiler does a lot of work for us. By default it implements `IComparable<T>`.

However, the code is embarrassing

```
type Either = | This | That
```

Yields:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
public sealed override int CompareTo(Either obj)
{
    if (this != null)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            int tag = _tag;
            int tag2 = obj._tag;
            if (tag == tag2)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return tag - tag2;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    if (obj != null)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the check `this != null` here?!

Comment: This is answered (for the case of IEquatable) here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8097472/59371

Comment: @marklam Funny, but it looks like reflection does not allow invoking instance methods against `null` target.

Comment: You can see exactly why that check is there if you try something like this:  `(None :> IComparable).CompareTo(Some ())`

Comment: @AaronM.Eshbach It's not quite valid example. After cast to interface F# emits `callvirt`.